# Tharpanam on the Grahanam day

Tags: rituals, eclipse

When should we have to do tarpanam on the grahanam or the eclipse day. Do we have to do before the start of Grahanam or after Moksha ?

Comment: during grahanam start veda arahmbha snanam, sankalpa, respective petaarhona (chandra/surya) mantra, japa should be started and in the middle do tarpanama and the end with japa and snanam again..

Comment: During eclipse time